# date_differenc not working

Tags: php, datediff

I am having the following error **"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date_diff() in D:\xampp\htdocs\DHatch\front\myprofile.php on line 334"**

My date_diff() function is

```
function date_diff($d1, $d2){
    $d1 = (is_string($d1) ? strtotime($d1) : $d1);
    $d2 = (is_string($d2) ? strtotime($d2) : $d2);

    $diff_secs = abs($d1 - $d2);
    $base_year = min(date("Y", $d1), date("Y", $d2));

    $diff = mktime(0, 0, $diff_secs, 1, 1, $base_year);
    $diffArray = array(
        "years" => date("Y", $diff) - $base_year,
        "months_total" => (date("Y", $diff) - $base_year) * 12 + date("n", $diff) - 1,
        "months" => date("n", $diff) - 1,
        "days_total" => floor($diff_secs / (3600 * 24)),
        "days" => date("j", $diff) - 1,
        "hours_total" => floor($diff_secs / 3600),
        "hours" => date("G", $diff),
        "minutes_total" => floor($diff_secs / 60),
        "minutes" => (int) date("i", $diff),
        "seconds_total" => $diff_secs,
        "seconds" => (int) date("s", $diff)
    );
    if($diffArray['days'] > 0){
        if($diffArray['days'] == 1){
            $days = '1 day';
        }else{
            $days = $diffArray['days'] . ' days';
        }
        return $days . ' and ' . $diffArray['hours'] . ' hours ago';
    }else if($diffArray['hours'] > 0){
        if($diffArray['hours'] == 1){
            $hours = '1 hour';
        }else{
            $hours = $diffArray['hours'] . ' hours';
        }
        return $hours . ' and ' . $diffArray['minutes'] . ' minutes ago';
    }else if($diffArray['minutes'] > 0){
        if($diffArray['minutes'] == 1){
            $minutes = '1 minute';
        }else{
            $minutes = $diffArray['minutes'] . ' minutes';
        }
        return $minutes . ' and ' . $diffArray['seconds'] . ' seconds ago';
    }else{
        return 'Less than a minute ago';
    }
}
```

and on **line 334**, there is a closing bracket of this function

Comment: It seems [someone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) beat you to it :)

Comment: no its working on development server but not working on my local server. i am using xampp

Comment: Look at the first few lines of the manual - (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0).

Answer (score 1):

`date_diff` is already in PHP.  You will have to name this something else or just use that one.

Comment: it sounds wired but its working fine on my development server. but not working on local server. i am using xampp

Comment: Or better yet, don't reinvent a native PHP function and just use the existing `date_diff`.